# How do I change a date to simply a year in excel?

Tags: excel, vba

How do I change a date to simply a year in excel? 1/2/1989 to just 1989?

Comment: What about =YEAR(A1)

Answer (score 3):

As a worksheet formula,

```
=YEAR(A1)
```

As VBA code,

```
dim yr as integer
yr = year(range("A1"))
```

Comment: ++ for giving both solutions :) @pnuts: seeing you after a long time:)

Comment: The Excel forum is just plain weird. @pnuts - glad to see you're back as part of it.